# Mahout Boolean pref data model with multiple "purchases"

Tags: mahout

I want to obtain reccomendations on the most purchased item for an order with a specific item so for example if I have such table

```
user order items purchased
1    1     1,3
1    2     2,3
2    1     3
3    1     2,4
3    2     1,2,4
```

if I visit the page of item 2 I want item 4 as suggested product because it is present on the rows 2,4 and 5 while the item 3 is present only on row 2 (I am considering just orders with the item 2 in it) (note that the item 3 is the most purchased but I don't want it as suggested since I am looking at item 2). What kind of problem is this? Is it an item reccomender? Is it doable in Mahout or should I implement it by hand? Since it is not possible to model multiple preferences per same user and item, I have thought to convert the string user_order to userId.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a very simple recommender problem. I think you want to ignore 'order'. So your data is more like:

```
1,1
1,3
1,2
2,3
3,2
3,4
3,1
```

Comment: but I want to make relevant the number of times the item is chosen. In this way we lose the information. For example the item 3 is chosen three times. I want to present the list of items that have been chosen the most with a specific item...

Comment: You could use the count as a 'rating' and that might work differently and better. But it's not really a rating so I would guess this may not help. Look at the implementation of alternating least squares in the project as ParallelALSFactorizationJob. The ALS model is much more suitable to the kind of count-based input you have.